# Write frame into MP4 format using opencv2 and c++

Tags: c++, opencv, video, frame, writefile

I am trying to write the frame into my local machine in mp4 format. The `frame` is read from an existing
mp4 file. After running the following code, I was able to see the `VideoOutput.mp4` file, but it is corrupted for some reason. Anyone knows why?

```
 VideoCapture capture("videoSample.mp4");
    if (capture.isOpened())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                capture >> frame;
            }
VideoWriter video("somepath\\videoOutput.mp4", VideoWriter::fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v'), 10, Size(win_width, win_width * 2));

    video.write(frame);
        }
```

Comment: Probably it needs some additional function for header writing.

Comment: if you give the VideoWriter the filename .mp4 extension and instead of using a fourcc, enter -1 as the codec, it works. At least in the newer opencv versions.

Comment: @Micka like this? `VideoWriter video("somepath\\videoOutput.mp4", VideoWriter::fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v'), 10, Size(win_width, win_width * 2));` It shows `tag 0x31313131/'1111' is not found (format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)')`

Comment: Does your video writer width/height match the frame width/height?  If it doesn't that will corrupt your output video.

Comment: no. like this: VideoWriter video("somepath\\videoOutput.mp4", -1, 10, Size(win_width, win_width * 2));